# open login screen when loading app

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-login

I have a like,share,win app on my website.

watch example on:
https://www.facebook.com/ExpertLemmer/app_358973127531240

The problem is when you click `like`, and your not logged in, FB opens the login screen, after login in it re-directs to my usual FB fanpage and not to the next app page. When already logged in it works like it should.

Is there a way to force people to log in when the first page is opened?

Comment: Wouldn't such an app be violating several Facebook policies at once? Also, how would users end up on the page tab while logged out?

Comment: I don`t know to be honest. https://www.expert.nl/lemmerwinactie is the link communicated in ads. This link redirects to the page tab. So i would like a FB login screen and then redirect to https://www.facebook.com/ExpertLemmer/app_358973127531240